# Does C have more macros like NULL?

Tags: c, null, hashtable

**Background:**

When deleting a cell in a hash table that uses linear probing you have to indicate that a value once existed at that cell but can be skipped during a search. The easiest way to solve this is to add another variable to store this information, but this extra variable can be avoided if an guaranteed invalid memory address is known and is used to represent this state.

**Question:**

I assume that since 0 is a guaranteed invalid memory address (more often than not), there must be more than just NULL. So my question is, does C provide a standard macro for any other guaranteed invalid memory addresses?

Comment: Technically, address 0 *could* be a valid address, e.g. on embedded systems. However, to answer your question, C have `NULL` as a pointer to "null" (which doesn't have to be `0`), and that's all.

Comment: Why do you need more?  NULL is sufficient and the only one.  Using extra bits in a pointer value is a common mistake btw, ends very poorly when the architecture changes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know that NULL is not strictly 0, but my question is since compilers can guarantee at least one address, why can't it guarantee more?

Comment: @MetaDark Then the simple answer is: The compilers and the runtime libraries are not required to, so why should they?. The specification says that there must be `NULL`, and some other symbolic constants, but no other pointer or address is mentioned.

Comment: In practice, it is *likely* that `((char*)NULL) + 1` or `((char*)NULL) - 1` will be invalid.  But this is not guaranteed since embedded systems may have address space restrictions (e.g. using 16- or 32-bit pointers instead of 64-bit).  For instance, `NULL` might be the largest possible pointer instead of the smallest, so the former expression will overflow.  Meanwhile, the latter expression underflows on most conventional systems.  I would strongly advise against trying to rely on either one.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok, that is perfectly reasonable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, `NULL` is not guaranteed to be invalid. It is only guaranteed not to be the address of any object (C11 6.3.2.3:3):

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant(66). If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.
>
> (66) The macro NULL is defined in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant

Your usage does not require the special address value to be invalid either: obviously, you are not accessing it, unless segfaulting is part of the normal behavior of your program.

So you could use the addresses of as many objects as you like, as long as the addresses of these objects are not intended to be part of the normal contents of a cell.

For instance, for an architecture where converting between pointers to objects preserve the representation, you could use:

```
char a, b, …;
#define NULL1 (&a)
#define NULL2 (&b)
…
```

Comment: This isn't a standard macro (I doubt one exists anyway), but it definitively solves the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, `NULL` is not required to be numerically zero at runtime.  C translates `0` and `NULL`, in a pointer context, into an implementation-defined invalid address.  That address is often numerically zero, but that is not guaranteed by the C standard.  To the best of my knowledge, C itself does not provide any invalid addresses guaranteed to be distinct from `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create your own 'invalid' address pointer:

`const void* const SOME_MARKER = (void*) &x;`

If you make sure that `x` (or its address) can never be actually used where you want to use `SOME_MARKER` you should be safe and 100% portable.